# Is it safe to use \usepackage{fullpage} for book publishing?

Tags: margins, books, book-design, layout, fullpage

I'm putting together a paperback book using the `\documentclass{book}` layout.

I'm starting to use `\usepackage{fullpage}` to get bigger fonts and gain more flexibility in terms of layout.

Final output will be a paperback 6 inches by 9 inches.

Has someone used `\usepackage{fullpage}` and got a paperback approved by KDP (Amazon)? Is it safe? Any issues?

Comment: That is really a question you have to work out with your publisher.  You are probably free to choose a font size (given it is within a reasonable range), but the margins will have to be compatible with the printer (both machine and person).

Comment: Have you thought of using the `memoir` class, which is a superset of the `book` class and provides many facilities for setting the layout and fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Peter. I didn't know (or thought) that the memoir class was for books. I think it might be really interesting. I also saw that there's provisions for createspace, which could work for me. Thank you!